# What about "ziemlich nicht..."?

Tags: word-usage

I was told by a native German speaker that these are correct:

> Das ist **nicht** gerecht.

and

> Das ist **ziemlich un**gerecht.

But that this is incorrect:

> Das ist **ziemlich nicht** gerecht.

because "ziemlich" and "nicht" can't be used together. Is this just an arbitrary rule for these 2 words or can someone put this in a grammatical context for me?

Comment: English is similar depending on how you translate *ziemlich*. "That's really not fair" sounds correct, while "That's rather not fair" does not. But perhaps "That's really not fair" in German is better as *Das ist wirklich nicht gerecht.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, *ziemlich* means "very":

> Das ist ziemlich ungerecht. "This is very unfair."

Given that meaning, *ziemlich nicht* doesn't make any sense:

> Das ist ziemlich nicht gerecht. "This is very not fair."

In German, as in English, there is no comparative or superlative of *nicht* "not". It is already an absolute. There is no "more not" or "very not".

Comment: WElcome to German SE. While I agree with your answer, I can tell you, that among friends there is "nicht", "wirklich nicht", "ganz und gar nicht", "überhaupt nicht", "niemals nicht", "überhaupt gar nie nicht" and so on ;-)

Comment: I would say that *ziemlich* means "rather", but that point is *ziemlich irrelevant* in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that "Das ist ziemlich nicht gerecht" is really wrong (at least in spoken language though it is not a euphony), but it has a slightly different meaning than "Das ist ziemlich ungerecht".

In "Das ist ziemlich ungerecht" the adverb *ziemlich* specifies the adjective *ungerecht* ("rather unfair"). In "Das ist ziemlich nicht gerecht" I would regard *ziemlich nicht* as an adverbial unit specifying the adjective *gerecht*. That is

- "**ziemlich nicht** gerecht" with an emphasis on **ziemlich nicht** is acceptable

whereas

- "ziemlich **nicht gerecht**"  with an emphasis on **nicht gerecht** would be wrong.

Here is another example.

Question: Ist es sicher, dass Du morgen kommst?

Answer: Das ist **ziemlich nicht** sicher.

In contrast to "ziemlich" the word "sehr" cannot be used in the combination *sehr nicht*. The sentence "Das ist sehr nicht gerecht" is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You could say "Das ist nicht sehr gerecht".

"Das ist nicht gerecht" is zero on a scale from 0 to 1.

"Das ist ziemlich ungerecht" is 7 or 8 on a scale from 0 to 10.

"Das ist nicht sehr gerecht" is 2 or 3 on a scale from 0 to 10.